# Does Visual Studio Code has a extensions similar to PTP (project sync tool) in Eclipse?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was using Eclipse PTP plugin to sync the code between my local and build server. It does not require the remote side to install anything (which is my requirement too as I can't install any software at that side), I believe internally it use Git. I am wondering does Visual Studio Code has a similar plugin.

Comment: Yes. Visual studio supports TFS and Git. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxd4dfad(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am using an extension call Sync-Rsync which work very well for me. I am able to use it because I confirmed that both local and remote has rsync installed. And I am very happy with this tool.